# Updating Angular 1.2.10 to latest with a minor bug (Overriding a href - third party)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I did,

I took this angularjs project and did nothing just updated it using nugget package manager to latest angular libraries,

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Learning-Path-Manager-Code-Sample

**Issue**

When I click on top right settings button, "Working On It" dialog appears and doesn't goes away.

**What I investigated**

Looking at url, when I click on "cog" url changes from,

https://omapny-ersda819baad8d.apps.com/sites/Dev1/lpm/app.html#/

to

https://omapny-ersda819baad8d.apps.com/sites/Dev1/lpm/app.html#

and dialog appears, but when I add "/" again, dialog disappears

what could be wrong ? I am totally new to AngualrJS

**Edit**

Most likely because it has this third party link,

```
<a id="chromeControl_topheader_apptitlelink" href="#" class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" target="_top"><span id="chromeControl_topheader_apptitle">Learning&nbsp;Path&nbsp;Manager</span></a>
```

How to get around this ?

Comment: I think I need to do something like this but not sure what exactly - http://www.developer.com/mgmt/angular.js-routes-with-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing followings,

for app title, I had to modify `appStartPage` to following,

```
function init() {
    // create chrome control settings
    spChromeControlData = {
        appStartPage: "app.html#/",
```

Above change is in spAppChrome.js controller file then in same file i added this within init function,

```
    //fix issues with chrome ctrl
    $('body').on('click', '.ms-core-menu-root', function () {
        $(this).attr("href", "javascript:;")
    });
```

So this will look something like this,

```
      // create the sharepoint chrome control
        var nav = new SP.UI.Controls.Navigation("chrome_ctrl_container", spChromeControlData);

        // show chrome control
        nav.setVisible(true);

        // hide top app chrome (image & app name)
        nav.setBottomHeaderVisible(false);

        //fix issues with chrome ctrl
        $('body').on('click', '.ms-core-menu-root', function () {
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:;")
        });

        logger.log("spAppChrome loaded", null, controllerId);
        common.activateController([], controllerId);
    }
```

Let me know if there's any issue.

Thanks